# Error 34513 when trying to re register Azure Backup Server

Tags: azure

I have tried downloading the MARS agent, new backup credentials and checked my server time as well as 20 other things. I still get error 34513 when trying to re register my Azure backup server. Anybody??

Comment: "Anybody??" This is the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the files inside `C:\Windows\Temp`
2. Reboot the Machine Locate
3. Locate the Credentials File on `C:\` - **not on the Desktop, not on a Network Share**
4. Try again, have fun!

For more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/troubleshooting-common-configuration-issues-with-azure-backup/